# How to get a category by its id?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a bot that creates channels. He must create channels in a certain category. I am using `guild.create_text_channel()`. I haven't found a way to do this in the documentation. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `discord.utils.get` for getting a category by it's id. Here is a usage of it:

```
guild = discord.utils.get(client.guild.categories, id='put the id here without apostrophes')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with this.

```py
from discord.utils import get

category = get(guild.category_channels, name="CATEGORY_NAME")
await guild.create_text_channel("CHANNEL_NAME", category=category)
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 if you are having issues with getting the channels in a category you can get the category by doing this

`category = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds[0].categories, id=CATEGORY_ID)`